# Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore: But it is an collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm facing the error:

> Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

I want to get all the docs from a specific collection but it says that the method getDocs needs a collection, but I passed an collection.

```
for (let year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++) {
    const cveSnapshot = await  getDocs(collection(db, `cves/${year}/cves`));

    console.log(cveSnapshot);

    for (const cveDoc of cveSnapshot.docs) {
        const cveData = cveDoc.data();
        if (await this.isObservationVulnerableToCVE(observation, cveData)) {
            matchingCVEs.push(cveData);
        }
    }
}
```

The year is 2023, so theres no problem with it.
This is the db:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider, onAuthStateChanged } from '@firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from '@firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show how `db` is initialized, and how the code that does that relates to the code you already shared.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @AlexMamo edited